# Mersenne Primes Generator in C#

Tags: c#, primes

I've made a program in C# that generates Mersenne numbers starting from the current largest known Mersenne prime. It then calculates the modulo between those numbers and smaller ones starting from 3 in order to figure out if it is divisible.

I've used some math tricks to make the process pretty fast, and so I can check the divisibility of what is basically a multi-million digit number against small numbers several times per second. However, I'd like to see if I can make it faster.

Also, if my program does work, it would suggest that the current largest known Mersenne prime (\$2^{74207281} - 1\$) is actually divisible by 7. Therefore I'm hesitant to say that my program actually does work, so if anyone can confirm this for me, I'd also greatly appreciate that!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Numerics;

namespace Prime
{
    public class Prime
    {
        const double C = 10601040; //this is a constant that I divide the exponent by to split it into the easiest possible chunks to work with
        static int exp = 74207281;
        static BigInteger big = BigInteger.Pow(2, exp) - 1;
        static TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"prime.txt"); //writes confirmed primes to a text file

        public static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = exp; true; i++) //this loop infinitely runs the prime checker, incrementing the exponent as it goes
            {
                exp++;
                primes(i);
            }
        }

        private static void primes(int exp)
        {
            double div = Math.Floor(exp/C),
                exp1 = div,
                exp2 = exp - (exp1*C), //this is where the exponent is divided into chunks
                result = 0; //anywhere this appears is just to make extra sure that the result stays zero outside the following loop, where the result really matters

            for (long i = 3; i <= (big/i); i+=2)
            {
                double result1 = (Math.Pow(2, exp1) % i)*C;
                double result2 = (Math.Pow(2, exp2) % i);
                result = (((result1 * result2) - 1) % i);
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exp + ", not prime.");
                    return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                result = 0;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(exp);
            tw.WriteLine(exp);
        }
    }
}
```

I modulo the chunks of the tested number against odd numbers because a Mersenne number will never be even, therefore it's a waste to check for that. Also, I made the stopping point for the loop dynamic so that any extra numbers can be cut out.
It's like this: 377 isn't divisible by 12, so we know that if it is divisible by something, it will be less than \$\frac{377}{12}\$, which is about 31.4. 377's actual factors are 13 and 29 (aside from itself and 1), which are both less than 37.7.

The technique used to modulo these massive numbers is known as modular exponentiation. It works for all numbers. Here's an example.

$2^7, C = 3, I = 5$

$2^7 = 128$

$Mersenne number being tested: 2^7 – 1 = 127 (this is prime)$

$Exp1 = 2$

$Exp2 = 1$

$Result1 = (2^2 % 5) * 3 = (2^2 % 5) * (2^2 % 5) * (2^2 % 5) = 4 * 4 * 4 = 64$

$Result2 = (2^1 % 5) = 2$

$Result = (  (  (64 * 2) – 1) % 5) = (  (  128 – 1) % 5) = (127 % 5) = 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> namespace Prime
> {
>     public class Prime
>     {
> ```

That's not very descriptive. I can tell that `Prime.Prime` has something to do with primes, but something like `NumberTheory.MersennePrimeTester` would be a lot more informative.

> ```
>         const double C = 10601040; //this is a constant that I divide the exponent by to split it into the easiest possible chunks to work with
> ```

Why is this a `double`? Why does its value give "*the easiest possible chunks to work with*"?

> ```
>         static int exp = 74207281;
> ```

Why is this a static field rather than a local variable?

> ```
>         static BigInteger big = BigInteger.Pow(2, exp) - 1;
> ```

Ditto. Also, why is this never updated?

> ```
>         static TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"prime.txt"); //writes confirmed primes to a text file
> ```

This also doesn't seem like it should be a static field.

> ```
>         public static void Main()
>         {
>             for (int i = exp; true; i++) //this loop infinitely runs the prime checker, incrementing the exponent as it goes
>             {
>                 exp++;
>                 primes(i);
> ```

`primes` is not a descriptive name. It's still unclear why `exp` is a field. This method would be much better as

```
public static void Main()
{
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"prime.txt");
    // Start at largest known Mersenne prime
    for (int i = 74207281; true; i++)
    {
        if (IsMersenneExponent(i)) tw.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

> ```
>         private static void primes(int exp)
>         {
>             double div = Math.Floor(exp/C),
>                 exp1 = div,
>                 exp2 = exp - (exp1*C), //this is where the exponent is divided into chunks
> ```

I asked before why `C` is `double`. It seems to me that this could be just

```
int exp1 = exp / C,
    exp2 = exp % C;
```

A comment explaining why you split the exponent up base `C` would be useful.

> ```
>                 result = 0; //anywhere this appears is just to make extra sure that the result stays zero outside the following loop, where the result really matters
> ```

WTF? That comment is more confusing than explanatory. What is the "*this*" of "*anywhere this appears*"? `result` doesn't even need to *exist* outside the loop.

> ```
>             for (long i = 3; i <= (big/i); i+=2)//***comment below
> ```

Was that a reminder to yourself to write a comment explaining what the loop is doing?

> ```
>                 double result1 = (Math.Pow(2, exp1) % i)*C;
>                 double result2 = (Math.Pow(2, exp2) % i);
>                 result = (((result1 * result2) - 1) % i);
> ```

JS1 has already addressed this in a previous answer: it looks very wrong.

> ```
>                 Console.WriteLine(i);
> ```

Why? This looks like debugging code which should have been removed before requesting code review.

A final note. The algorithm appears to be trial division. That's of no practical use for numbers on the order of 2<sup>256</sup>, let alone 2<sup>74207281</sup>. The reason that the majority of the largest known primes are Mersenne is that there's a highly optimised primality test for Mersenne primes. Look into the [Lucas-Lehmer test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test).

Comment: The names I give my functions, class, and namespace are just there for simplicity. I didn't see a whole lot of need to be very specific with them. Though I should probably leave a comment explaining that. Those specified variables are doubles because C# likes any variables involved in math to be of the same data type and Math.Floor returns either decimal or double. Yes, some pieces of code are more of a debugging nature. I will make a note to remove those sorts of things in the future.

Comment: As for the comment on the return=0, I meant that I was using that statement to ensure that the variable stayed 0 unless it was within the scope of the primes function's for loop. Finally, the "***comment below" comment wasn't so much a reminder as it was a note that the comment below referred to that piece of code.

Comment: You don't need `Math.Floor` if you're doing integer division of positive numbers.

Comment: I think I kinda do because even so, without rounding down, I'm likely to get a non-whole number. I divide the massive exponent into single digit pieces which are easier to handle, round down that number so I'm not doing 2^8.3, and dump the remainder on the variable exp2. I hope I explained that well enough. I could tell from your answer that I didn't explain a whole lot very well.

Comment: Also, I did look into the Lucas-Lehmer test. It does look fairly simple, but I'm not sure if it's any faster because all it does is square numbers over and over again. Given the massive exponent I'm dealing with, I feel it would kill efficiency. All the same, I will put together a program for it and see if it is any better later on. I appreciate the suggestion. :)

Comment: 1. Integer division means division using `int` (or `byte`, `short`, `long`, etc.) It can never give a non-whole number because the type cannot represent non-whole numbers. It gives the whole number part, and the modulus operator (`%`) gives the remainder. 2. The Lucas-Lehmer test has been used to prove some very large Mersenne primes. Trying to prove their primality using trial division would not terminate in the lifetime of the universe using the entire world's computing power.

Comment: I did not know that quotients were automatically floored when placed in ints. Definitely saves some space there. :) Thanks! Also, I have just finished putting together a short script that uses the Lucas-Lehmer test. It's rather resource intensive, to say the least. I'm going to try using a few math tricks to speed it up. Do you have any suggestion as to where I should post the script for further discussion? Shall I create another question? Again, thank you. :)

Comment: Yes, if you have a rewritten version following feedback then AIUI you're welcome to post a new question here (probably linking back to this one for context) to get the new version reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

#### Bug

This line seems wrong:

> ```
> double result1 = (Math.Pow(2, exp1) % i)*C;
> ```

It seems like you are implying that:

\$x^y \mod m = ((x \mod m)*y) \mod m\$

But I believe the actual relationship is:

\$x^y \mod m = (x \mod m)^y \mod m\$

This probably explains why your program thinks the known Mersenne prime is divisible by 7.

#### Loop termination, or lack of it

Your loop is like this:

> ```
> for (long i = 3; i <= (big/i); i+=2)//***comment below
> ```

But `big` is \$2^{74207281} - 1\$.  Therefore, you intend your loop to run until `i` reaches \$\sqrt {2^{74207281}-1}\$, meaning `i` needs to reach about \$2^{37103640}\$.  Unfortunately, your loop index is a `long` and not a `BigInteger`, so it can't even represent the numbers you need to represent.  But even if you made `i` a `BigInteger`, the loop would run virtually forever because you would need to reach that huge number before you could stop.

Comment: Actually, what I'm trying to do there is called modular exponentiation.

Comment: Link: [Khan Academy - Modular exponentiation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-exponentiation)

Comment: @Paradox Try what you are doing with smaller numbers and you'll see that what you are doing doesn't work.  For example, try with \$2^7\$ and `C = 3`.

Comment: Okay, so the absurdly high minimum loop limit is indeed a problem that I'd like to fix. Thank you for making it clearer as to where that would be. I shall be looking into that in order to find a better way of cutting that down more. As for testing out the modular exponentiation with smaller numbers, I will make an edit to the question to draw out that test.