# Mersenne Prime Checker using Lucas-Lehmer Formula

Tags: c#, primes

Previously I created a C# script that used trial division to check to see whether or not certain Mersenne numbers were prime. Since these numbers are so big, I employed some math shortcuts to reduce the amount of division I needed to do. It was brought to my attention that using the Lucas-Lehmer formula would speed up the process significantly. Here's a link to the post I made before. [Link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144404/mersenne-primes-generator-in-c)

In this new script, I have included functions for two versions of the formula. The first is the original, while the second one uses bit shifting and is said to be more memory efficient and take fewer operations compared to the first.

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace Prime
{
    public class LucasLehmer
    {
        static int exp = 74207281;
        static BigInteger two = 2;
        static BigInteger mersenne = BigInteger.Pow(two, exp) - 1;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; true; i++)
            {
                LucasLehmerFuncBinary(exp, mersenne);
                exp++;
            }

        }

        private static void LucasLehmerFunc(int exp, BigInteger mersenne)                //regular lucas lehmer formula
        {
            BigInteger s = 4;
            BigInteger result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < (exp - 2); i++)
            {
                result = ((s*s) - 2) % mersenne;
                s = result;
                Console.WriteLine(i + " , " + s); //debug statement
            }

            if (result == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Two to the power " + exp + " minus one is prime.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Two to the power " + exp + " minus one is not prime.");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void LucasLehmerFuncBinary(int exp, BigInteger mersenne) //a more memory and time efficient binary modification of the formula
    {
        BigInteger s = 2;
        BigInteger result = 1;
        while (exp > 0)
        {
            if (exp % 2 == 1)
            {
                result = (result * s) % mersenne;
                Console.WriteLine("result length: " + result.ToString().Length); //debug statement
            }

            exp = exp >> 1;
            s = (s * s) % mersenne;
            Console.WriteLine("exp: " + exp); //debug statement
            Console.WriteLine("s: " + s.ToString().Length); //debug statement
        }

        if (result == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two to the power " + exp + " minus one is prime.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Two to the power " + exp + " minus one is not prime.");
        }
    }
}
```

Concerning the lines

```
result = ((s*s) - 2) % mersenne;
result = (result * s) % mersenne;
s = (s * s) % mersenne;
```

all of these get incredibly big after just a few iterations.

I was thinking about using scientific notation to make the process of multiplying much easier because it's easier multiplying numbers in this form. Could anyone help me figure out how best to implement this?

Are there any other methods I could use to make it easier for a computer to do math with numbers that are, as it turns out, hundreds of thousands of digits long, if not millions?